# Effort (C#) - 'Sequence contains no matching element' when seeding data to any of my entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, effort

I am trying to build some unit tests for a few web service calls in my project. I am using Entity Framework 6.1.3 in my project to retrieve the data at the service layer (with a code-first approach). I did some research on how to Mock a DatabaseContext object and I found out that Effort can do this.

I followed the documentation when implementing Effort in my unit tests but when I try to seed data to my entities I get a "System.InvalidOperationException: 'Sequence contains no matching element'" exception. I am not entirely sure why this is happening. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Here is how the code looks like....

```
  //THE CALLER -- Doing what Effort suggests to do.

    var dbConnection = DbConnectionFactory.CreateTransient();
        FakeDbContext = new FakeDbContext(dbConnection);
        DatabaseSeed.AddTestData(FakeDbContext);
```

Here is where I seed data to the entities...

```
public static void AddTestData(IFakeDbContext context)
    {
        //**************** IT CRASHES HERE *********************
        context.FakeEntity1.AddOrUpdate(new FakeEntity1 
        {
           Name1 = "TestingName1",
           LastName1 = "TestingLastName1"

        });

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Here is my Entity Model...

```
[Table("rpt.FakeEntity1")]
public partial class FakeEntity1 : IFakeEntity1 
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string Name1 { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string LastName1 { get; set; }

}
```

Here is my DatabaseContext...

```
public partial class FakeDbContext: IFakeDbContext
{

    public FakeDbContext(DbConnection dbConnection) 
                          : base(dbConnection, true)
    {
        //Effort requires this.
    }

}

public interface IFakeDbContext :IDisposable
{

    DbSet<FakeEntity1> FakeEntity1 {get; set;}

}
```

I also have another class FakeDbContext.Base that overrides OnModelCreating.

Here is the Stack Trace:

[StackTrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1O5mo.png)

Comment: @GertArnold I just attached the stack trace.

Comment: You're probably using data types that Effort doesn't support: https://github.com/tamasflamich/effort/issues/10

Comment: @GertArnold You were right I had other entities using unsupported data types by Effort. Thanks!

Comment: @GetArnold can you post an answer please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stack trace shows that the exception is thrown when the data provider is looking for a "store type from name". This indicates that you're using a data type that Effort doesn't support. This is confirmed by an [issue in the Effort project](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Effort/issues/10).

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps.

Many answers says you have to add `FirstorDefault()` in your EF statements but this error also occurs in the incorrect properties using data annotations.

When using Data Annotations, be careful with the properties that you add.

Example below, I missed the `TypeName = "string"`, which should have been `nvarchar` as it is the data type in the database.

Also, take note of the `Order = n`,(starts with 0)

Encountered this while updating a past colleagues source code.

```
[Display(Name = "Name")]
[MaxLength(4000)]
[Column("Name", Order = 14, TypeName = "string")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

then I corrected my code with

```
[Display(Name = "Name")]
[MaxLength(4000)]
[Column("Name", Order = 15, TypeName = "nvarchar")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

:)